# Full file names in ES File Explorer

Tags: files, es-file-explorer

In ES File Explorer, each folder has its name underneath it.  But if the name is long, only a truncated version of it appears.  How can I see the full name?

Bonus question: is there a more general way of seeing full file names when only partial names are shown?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ES File Explorer is on the default view, which is Large Icon, long-press the folder/file, then select **More - Properties** to see its full name.

For a general solution (in case there are many folders/files with long names), the alternative is to change the view to list by selecting **View - (any) List/Detail**. In most cases, it will display a long enough name. The downside is fewer folders/files are shown.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Andrew's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105862/44325) (Selecting **More --> Properties** on the bottom right corner of the app)

You can also select the file and press **Rename** on the bottom next to delete.